# Addressing CRUD "tables" in event sourcing

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm starting down an ES journey and want to know if traditional support tables should be stored in the event log or should those be handled differently? These tables would typical have a CRUD page. In other words, would it be common to have 2 approaches in the same application, one for support tables and one for transactional data?

A support table would be like "Account" in an accounting application or "Product Type" or the actual "Product" table in an ERP application (I'm not writing an ERP application - that's an example of the type of table I'm talking about).

If we store CRUD-type data in the event log, then we might have events:

- ProductCreated
- ProductUpdated
- ProductDeleted (which would just mark it as deleted)

Then, do we attempt to find out what changed (in ProductUpdated event) and just store the change and replay to get the latest image of the Product?

Mostly, I'm after what approach to use for CRUD tables - traditional or store in the event log? Additional information would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by "support table"?

Comment: Okay, let me try again. Consider the Stackoverflow application. They have tags. Those tags are stored in a table somewhere and they "support" the application, providing table data in a normalized relational kind of way (if they follow a traditional approach). Rather than store the tag and its description in every question, Stackoverflow likely has a tag table and the question merely stores the id to the tag. A question can exist without it, but it supports it and provides additional attributes which are further defined by the table attributes (like tag description).

Comment: I think I now understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you start purely with an event log, including for events like `ProductCreated`, etc., and no other data store. What happens then is that every time your application starts up, it has to replay *all* the events in the log to build its current state.

Now, suppose you create a traditional SQL table to store the current state of your app (say a `products` table) *and the ID of the last event that was processed to get to that state* (say a `last_event` table). What happens then is every time your app starts up, it has to replay *only* the events with higher IDs than the stored ID and process those to build its new state.

On the flip side, your app now has to be careful to keep these two states synchronised. If you need to have concurrency, you'll need to be careful to do atomic operations only on your SQL tables--but that should be reasonably easy with transacctions.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'm a little puzzled though by your comment that the application has to replay all the events. If a user requests to see a product, for example, then the application has to replay to get the final state, but that would only be when there's a need for the product. With regard to keeping synchronized, I believe it is a common pattern to maintain a readonly easily queried view. With a reliable message broker of some sort, this shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: @OutfastSource I'm talking about what happens if your app shuts down and restarts. Unless it persisted its up-to-date state somewhere, it will need to replay the entire event log to build it up again. But if it did persist its state, it will need to ensure that the persisted state is consistent with the event log.

Answer (score 1):

Your support tables are just a read-model/projection of the event stream. In general you don't create those support models in case you need them. You create a read-model only if you use it somewhere in the `UI`.

Anyway, one important benefit behind `Event sourcing` is that you won't need to use `join` in your queries. That is, you create a `table` for each `read-model` that contains all the data it needs - full denormalisation. You keep that table super-optimised for the query.

Comment: What I've been seeing is that people, you included, seem to treat these support tables as second class citizens. Why aren't they part of the event stream as you say? They are considered critical business data, like Account in an accounting system. They are integral to the context of the transactional data. I expect to create read-only/projection tables, that's just a representation of the event log and the event log will store all critical data (again, like Account), right?

Comment: Read-models contains critical data. They are important. But they are different from write-models. They have different purposes. They can be optimized differently. They should be treated differently.

Comment: Are you calling transactional data, like a sales order, for example, a write-model and support data read-models?

Comment: Update: I researched read-models a bit. This is after the data is inserted that the read-model gets utilized, right. Doesn't the data get inserted, initially, in the event log? Therefore would CRUD tables (support tables) get inserted/updated via the event log?

Comment: After the `Aggregate` (the write model) generate the events, the events are persisted in the event log then all interested read-models receive these events and update their databases. So there are 2 writes to 2 databases.